# Docker: Edit "my.cnf" file in stopped container

Tags: mysql, docker

After making an edit to "my.cnf", I now get an error from Kitematic on the Mac when I attempt to start the container:

```
mysqld: [ERROR] Found option without preceding group in config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf at line 19! mysqld: 
        [ERROR] Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted!
```

I've tried accessing the container via:

```
docker exec -it [container] bash
```

... but I get the error:

```
Error response from daemon: Container [container] is not running
```

I was able to access *something* via the image, but the file didn't appear to be the same, so I'm not sure what was happening (I'm not too conversant with Docker).

At this stage, either making the appropriate edit and fixing the container, or somehow cloning the MySQL data to another container would be ideal.

Comment: Plan now for what you’ll need to do when you need to delete and recreate the container for a critical MySQL security fix.  (Editing the file in the container will get lost when you do that.)

Comment: I won't be using Docker, that's for the certain.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To fix the my.cnf, you can use `docker container cp`. It works with stopped containers.

1. To copy file from your container to current path

```
docker container cp containerId:/etc/mysql/my.cnf container-my.cnf
```

2. Then edit container-my.cnf and copy back from path to container :

```
docker container cp container-my.cnf containerId:/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

---

To use the existing MySQL data with a new container:

```
docker container inspect -f '{{.Mounts}}' [container]
```

gives you the volume name (key `volume`) where the data is. Then start a new mysql container and mount the volume under `/var/lib/mysql`:

```
docker container run -d -v [volume_name]:/var/lib/mysql [image]
```

Afterwards you can remove the old container (Actually you can remove it before creating the new one)

Comment: When I try this in Windows 10 I get a symlink back, and it doesn't link to anything.

Comment: not work, its says "A required privilege is not held by the client."

Comment: Its working ! Since file editing wasn't working for me, I created another Docker container using the same image. I get the default configuration file using the above command and move that configuration file to the stopped container. After doing this, it started working for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the official mysql docker image from

https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql

you can use a custom MySQL configuration file that overrides my.cnf

If /my/custom/config-file.cnf is the path and name of your custom  configuration file, you can start your mysql container like this (note that only the directory path of the custom config file is used in this command):

```
$ docker run --name some-mysql -v /my/custom:/etc/mysql/conf.d -e  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mysql:tag
```

This will start a new container some-mysql where the MySQL instance uses the combined startup settings from /etc/mysql/my.cnf and /etc/mysql/conf.d/config-file.cnf, with settings from the latter taking precedence.