# How can I access the my.cnf file from stopped mysql docker container on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, docker

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55581409/docker-edit-my-cnf-file-in-stopped-container) , but when I try to run it a symlink was created instead of copying the file. It didn't work, this is what I get:

[image]

I added some badly formatted info to the file, now the container keeps restarting. Since it's restarting I can't do `docker container exec -it /bin/bash`.
I tried copying the file while the container was starting and response is "The system cannot fine the file specified"

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Apart from this badly formatted content, have you performed customization on image's default `cnf` file that you want to keep?  If not just delete the container and start over.

Comment: Well, there was a significant amount of data in there already, but in the end that's what I did. I'll leave the question open for a while, in case there is some sort of solution.